# Create a documentation side-webapp for main app

Tags: git, vue.js, branch

I have Vue project with custom classes and components to use in the main project.

I want these to be documented on some sort of page. Right now I have a /documentation url in Vue-Router, but it's not optimal to have this on production.

My question is, is it possible to disable this route on production, or to have a second side project which only has this route?

For example, would it be viable to set up a theming branch on git which has these components and css rules, but not any other component/.vue file? Everything there would be related to the theme, and updates to the theme would be made to this branch and then merged back into the develop branch.

Or is there any other solution? The idea is to have a reliable page where everything can be accessed but not public.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is it possible to disable this route on production

You can create two entry points (so one more main.js) and in one of them add only the documentation route. Then configure the server to serve your second app under `/documentation`.

---

> Or to have a second side project which only has this route

You could create some sort of "library" project containing your documentation and componends. Some tools to consider: lerna, bitsrc.io

---

Its pretty common to document components in storybook. You can easily create interactive, in-context demo scenarios. It is really simple to set up, but I'm not sure about possibilities of documenting classes.

---

Anyways, you've got some addresses to check, do some reading and you'll be able to find something best suiting the needs of your case.